# Indicate language for VoiceOver in macOS / AppKit

Tags: macos, accessibility, appkit, voiceover

I work on an app for foreign language learning. So some interface elements (usually `NSTextField`) contain text in a language different from the system language.
This is an issue with VoiceOver because it will then read out foreign words using the system voice.

[On iOS each view has a property `accessibilityLanguage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615192-accessibilitylanguage/) that allows to indicate the language of the element so VoiceOver uses the correct voice.
On macOS I could not find any similar API. The only way I found was to use `NSAttributedString` with the `accessibilityLanguage` attribute. But this is [not well documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/2890803-accessibilitylanguage/) and in fact did not work. Also, I could not properly debug it because the attributes are not visible in the Accessibility Inspector.

Does anybody know of a way to properly indicate the accessibility language on macOS / AppKit?

Comment: hey @codingFriend1 - were you able to find the solution to this?

Comment: @cieplik No, unfortunately not.